# Xampp php7 not starting mac os X

Tags: php, macos, apache, xampp, php-7

I uninstall xampp with php 5.6 and download and install my xampp with php7.

Then I use the manage server to start the Apache Web Server, the light red turns on a yellow light, but after returns to red light.

The Application log show this:
Starting Apache Web Server...
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd started

[image]

What´s happening here?

Answer (score 2):

open your terminal and write this command and press enter

```
sudo apachectl stop
```

to stop your apache osx and re-open your apache

Good Luck